# Mysql: sum case with multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following table:

table1:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     person varchar(30), 
     color_code varchar(30),
     item_id varchar(30),
     date_start DATE, 
     date_complete DATE 
    );

INSERT INTO table1
(person, color_code, item_id, date_start, date_complete)
VALUES
('Jackson', 'RED', '1', '2013-07-11 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Danny', 'BLUE', '2', '2013-07-20 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Jimmy', 'GREEN', '5', '2013-05-15 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Jackson', 'RED', '3', '2013-02-16 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Jimmy', 'BLUE', '4', '2013-03-13 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('William', 'RED', '5', '2013-04-29 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('William', 'BLUE', '1', '2013-05-9 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Danny', 'GREEN', '5', '2013-01-6 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Jackson', 'RED', '4', '2013-07-11 11:23:39', '2013-08-1 11:23:39'),
('Jackson', 'RED', '5', '2013-08-7 11:23:39', '2013-09-1 11:23:39');
```

table2:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     item_code varchar(30), 
     item_name varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO table2
(item_code, item_name)
VALUES
('1', 'APPLE'),
('2', 'BANANA'),
('3', 'PINEAPPLE'),
('4', 'WATERMELON'),
('5', 'GUAVA');
```

my sql query look like this:

```
SELECT 

    person AS 'Name',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total Item Purchased',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='RED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Red Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='BLUE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Blue Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='GREEN') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Green Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date_complete, date_start) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Bought Between 1-30 Days'

FROM table1

    WHERE 
    person LIKE '%Jackson%' OR
    person LIKE '%Danny%' OR
    person LIKE '%Jimmy%' OR
    person LIKE '%William%'
    GROUP BY person;
```

**Problem:** How do i display the **item_name** from **table2** to the select query with all the row group by the **person**? im thinking about subselect, after the **'Bought Between 1-30 Days'** is it possible?

[image: Sample output that i want]

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59e0/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables and use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT 

    person AS 'Name',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total Item Purchased',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='RED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Red Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='BLUE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Blue Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='GREEN') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Green Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date_complete, date_start) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Bought Between 1-30 Days',
    GROUP_CONCAT(item_name)

FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.item_code = table1.item_id

    WHERE 
    person LIKE '%Jackson%' OR
    person LIKE '%Danny%' OR
    person LIKE '%Jimmy%' OR
    person LIKE '%William%'
    GROUP BY person;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59e0/6/2).

Note that it is sometimes better to simply join the tables and sort the resultset by `person`, performing such aggregation within the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: @David: Following the link to the MySQL documentation, "*This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.*"

Comment: is it possible to manipulate the GROUP_CONCAT() to display multiple field. Example: i have item_name and item_manufacture, then i want to show it as: 
APPLE - Australia
Banana - America

seperate by newline instead of comma. is it possible?

Comment: @David: You can combine with MySQL's [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function - `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' - ', item_name, item_manufacture) SEPARATOR '\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables

```
SELECT 

    person AS 'Name',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total Item Purchased',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='RED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Red Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='BLUE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Blue Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (color_code='GREEN') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Green Color',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date_complete, date_start) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Bought Between 1-30 Days',
    item_name as 'item'

FROM table1,table2

    WHERE 
    table1.item_id = table2.item_code and (
    person LIKE '%Jackson%' OR
    person LIKE '%Danny%' OR
    person LIKE '%Jimmy%' OR
    person LIKE '%William%')
    GROUP BY person;
```

Check the js http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d59e0/13